# How to get IObservable<T>.ToTask functionality in silverlight

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

How can I achieve the behavior you get with IObservable ToTask method in Silverlight where the TPL is not provided ?
I want exceptions to get promoted up results as IEnumerable and be able to block and wait for Observable to complete.

Here is an example of what I'm doing with ToTask :

```
int collectionSize = 200;
service.Collection.CreateSampleCollection(size: collectionSize).Wait();
var query = (QuerySource)service.Collection.CollectionTestModel.All();
var queryTask = query.ToTask();
query.Fetch();
var entities = queryTask.Result;
CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(entities.Select(e => (int)(long)e["Number"]), Enumerable.Range(0, collectionSize));
service.Collection.DeleteTestCollection().Wait();
```

So what would be a simple way to translate this code in to other RX extensions ?
Using Run I have to add onNext and onError(?) and I have to aggregate the results in onNext. Is there a simpler way to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `First()` to block until there is a value available (likewise, `Last` also blocks).

If you need *all* the values, you can [download the latest build of Rx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896.aspx) and use `.ToArray().First()`.

Answer (score 1):

And if you don't have the latest build of Rx, ToList is easy enough to write anyways:

```
public static List<T> ToList<T>(this IObservable<T> This)
{
    return This.Aggregate(new List<T>(), (acc, x) => {
        acc.Add(x);
        return acc;
    }).First();
}
```

Comment: `ToArray` / `ToList` are non-blocking (returns `IObservable<T[]>`), so I'd remove the `First()` to properly replicate it.